# Centos usermod -a don't add a user to a group

Tags: linux, centos, user-mode-linux

In my project i have to create a group on my centos server and add two users; i do:

```
sudo groupadd editorial
```

then i try to add my two users to group like this:

```
sudo usermod -a -G editorial nginx
sudo usermod -a -G editorial ec2-user
```

ok, no errors, but when i check my group:

```
sudo groups editorial
```

in output i get:

> groups: editorial: no such user

why i cannot add my user to group?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks more like a general Linux question than a programming question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You can try the command `sudo groups username`. It will show you the user in which group.

Answer (score 0):

Your form of the command is wrong. You separate the supplemental groups with `commas` not `whitepsace`, man usermod:

```
-G A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member of. Each 
   group is separated from the next by a comma, with no intervening whitespace.
```

Example:

```
sudo usermod -a -G editorial,nginx nameofuser
```

And this questions is somewhat a close call, if you are writing a script to do this, then that is probably OK on StackOverflow, but if this is just a general "How do I use `usermod`", that should probably go to [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: if i use commas i have an error, in this tutorial whitespace is used: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-users-and-groups-in-linux-from-the-command-line/

Comment: That's is really really strange. You need to provide the user. I'll edit. Note; use the real username where I have `nameofuser`.

Answer (score 0):

silly question.. but have you done "$sudo useradd nameofuser" before trying usermod?